# SQLite database always empty (FMDB)

Tags: ios, objective-c, sqlite, fmdb

I'm doing a very classic routine that i've done multiple times, but in this project, its not working. When I want to work with my DB, I get " No such tables " errors. Which should be wrong. I checked the bundle database and its fine ; I checked the "result" db in the phone and its completly empty (no structure, and obviously no data).

Here is my DB creation routine. I call it every time I need the database.

```
+ (FMDatabase*)createAndCheckDataBase{
    BOOL success;
    NSArray *docPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDir = [docPaths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *databasePath = [documentsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"database.sqlite"];
    NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    success = [fileManager fileExistsAtPath:databasePath];

    //The database already exist in the application folder, we don't need to create it
    if(success){
        return [FMDatabase databaseWithPath:databasePath];
    }

    NSString *databasePathFromApp = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"database.sqlite"];
    [fileManager copyItemAtPath:databasePathFromApp toPath:databasePath error:nil];

    return [FMDatabase databaseWithPath:databasePath];
```

Then i just do `FMDatabase *db = [DatabaseManager createAndCheckDatabase];`and i supposedly get my db. But i don't.

I created the sqlite database using the SQLite Manager plugin from Firefox, created the structure there, then imported it into the bundle.

Note : success always return true.

Any help is most welcome!

Comment: Check if the file copy works (hint: it returns a `BOOL` value to tell you) and if not, find out why (hint: it returns an `NSError` object to tell you).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the comments mentioned, you need to check the copy.

Here's a snippet from my code which checks whether the copy succeeded and returns the error details to the consumer

```
//
// notice our method to prepare the db returns bool and doesn't lose the error details
// the consumer can log, present, whatever - this is a library function
//
- (BOOL)ensureDatabasePrepared: (NSError **)error
{
    // <snip bunch of code>

    // copy db from template to library
    if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:_dbPath])
    {
        NSLog(@"db not exists");

        // notice how we pass in the error ref passed to this function
        if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] copyItemAtPath:dbTemplatePath toPath:_dbPath error:error])
        {
            return NO;
        }

        NSLog(@"copied");
    }
```

Comment: Yep, the filepath wasn't correct, therefore the copy wasn't at the right path either. This is because i changed the bundle name couple of days ago and the .app didn't change. This caused an issue in the path. Renaming everything with the correct name fixed it, and looking at the error showed me way ;) Thank man !

Comment: @Zil - I find it useful to execute a simple "sanity test" immediately after doing the copy -- access some dummy data, etc.

Comment: @HotLicks Yeah, that's a habit I should have !
Thanks for being here on stack btw, I often see your useful comments/answers :)